# missing requirement osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I have a error during Karaf 4.0.5 start. I get this error:

```
(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[Tracking_Service [11](R 11.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)[4:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.4]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

Can you give some advice how I can solve this issue?

I use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have built your bundle using OSGi Release 6, however you are deploying onto an OSGi Framework version of a lower/earlier version.